# Having trouble in fillpoly attribute in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'fillPolly'.

I also tried this by installing and uninstalling but couldn't worked
`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

```py
def area_of_interest(image): 
    height = image.shape[0]
    polygons = np.array([ 
        [(500, height ), 
         (1100, height), 
         (800, 458)] ]) 
    mask = np.zeros_like(image) 
    cv2.fillPolly(mask, polygons, 255) 
    return mask
```

Comment: Please show your code and where the error occurs.

Comment: def area_of_interest(image):
    height = image.shape[0]
    polygons = np.array([
        [(500, height ), (1100, height), (800, 458)]
        ])
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.fillPolly(mask, polygons, 255)
    return mask

Comment: How did you import opencv in your code and how did you install it? This double cv2.cv2 has been answered many times on this forum. Search this forum or Google it and you wlll likely find the answer. Please read this forums help section about how to provide minimum, repeatable code and how to ask good questions.